# unique_ptr<T>.get() method call destructor while assigning with raw pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, crash, unique-ptr

The below program uses `std::unique_ptr<T>` to avoid manual memory management. There are two ways I have tried to implement it. The problem is in the second approach, before assigning to raw pointer, destructor is getting called. This results into the crash of the program as later code tries to access invalid memory.

My intention in the second approach is, how to use the smart pointer with existing code base so that I can make use of automatic memory management provided by smart pointer. Hence I did not change the type of pointer in declaration(.i.e. From `Widget* w` to `std::unique_ptr<Widget> w`).

Could somebody explain it in bit detail and what should be the best practice?. Or I am missing something?.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
class Widget {
public:
    Widget() { std::cout << "Widget::Widget()" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Widget() { std::cout << "Widget::~Widget()" << std::endl; }
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class WindowsButton : public Widget {
public:
    WindowsButton() = default;
    ~WindowsButton() = default;
    void draw() { std::cout << "WindowsButton"<<std::endl; }
};

int main() {    
    // Working Code
    // std::unique_ptr<Widget> w = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new WindowsButton());
    // w.get()->draw();

    //In this way program is crashing while calling the w->draw()
    Widget* w = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new WindowsButton()).get();
    w->draw();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with simply making `w` a `std::unique_ptr<Widget>`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: There is no problem to change the prototype. But as I had mentioned in the SO that I wanted to do it in the existing code base.

Comment: There's no need for `w.get()->draw();` in the first case, `unique_ptr` provides an `operator->()` overload, so `w->draw();` works.

Comment: You'll have to construct a `std::unique_ptr` and then call `get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you misunderstood a bit of `unique_ptr`. It is not a means to *help* with the memory management of raw pointers, but to *replace* raw pointers. In both of your examples you fall back to call `get()` on your `unique_ptr` to obtain a raw poitner and work with it. That is not needed. You can do with a `unique_ptr` all you are used to do with a raw pointer, except copying it and calling `delete`.

The issue you encounter in your second example is an issue of lifetimes. Since `unique_ptr` owns the object it points to it controls its lifetime, meaning the object has to be destroyed when the `unique_ptr` gets destroyed. Since the `unique_ptr` is a temporary one, it destroys the object in the same line.

As a corollary, temporary `unique_ptr`s are of little use, except if you use them to initialize another `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr` or some other object that takes over ownership and therefore leaves the `unique_ptr` empty.

In the following lines I'll polish up your "working code" a bit:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> w = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new WindowsButton());
w.get()->draw();
```

This is ok in the sense of safety and semantics, you do nothing bad here. But as I said, the call to `get()` is unnecessary, as is the explicit copy initialization:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> w(new WindowsButton());
w->draw();
```

This is the C++03-style way to use it, and it's okay for C++11, too. People give different advice on how and when to use C++11 features like `auto` and uniform initialization, so here are a few examples that will be good/better in C++11, too:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget> w{new WindowsButton{}};
```

or even

```
auto w{std::unique_ptr<Widget>{new WindowsButton{}}};
```

(which I consider rather ugly).

In C++14 there is `make_unique` and the advice to almost never use `new`, so your initialization would look like this:

```
auto w{std::make_unique<WindowsButton>()};
```

Here, `w` has type `std::unique_ptr<WindowsButton>` but this normally won't hurt since it is convertible to `std::unique_ptr<Widget>` if needed.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case you're creating a temporary instance of a `unique_ptr` and calling the `get()` member function on it. The `unique_ptr` object will be destroyed at the end of the full expression (at the semicolon).

```
Widget* w = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new WindowsButton()).get();
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^
//          unnamed temporary instance                        destroyed here
```

Naturally, the `unique_ptr` will `delete` the managed object when the instance is destroyed, and that calls `~Widget()`.

```
w->draw();
```

will then dereference a pointer to an invalid memory location, leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
Widget* w = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(new WindowsButton()).get();
```

the `unique_ptr` is a temporary object and gets destructed by the time the line is finished executing. Hence, the `Widget` gets destructed too. That explains the segmentation violation when you call

```
w->draw();
```

At that time, `w` is a dangling pointer.